# Smoluchowski-Poisson dynamics with atomic measures

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes

"Smoluchowski-Poisson dynamics" is just a tentative provisional name I give to the following transport equation:$$\partial_t m+\nabla_x\cdot(um)=0$$where $u(x,t)\in\mathbb R^n$ ($x\in\mathbb R^n$, $t\ge0$) is the gradient of a solution $f$ to the Poisson equation$$u=\nabla f,\ \ \Delta_x f=c'm$$i.e. (more precisely)$$u(x)=c\int_{\mathbb R^n} \frac{(y-x)\ m(dy)}{|y-x|^n}$$($c$ or $c'$ is a physical constant). The case I'm interested in is when the sign of $c$ is such that the velocity $u$, by which the (nonnegative) measure $m$ is transported, is *attractive*, resulting in atoms being formed and coalescing in finite time (to a final single atom if $m$ is finite).

My question is twofold:
1°) Does this equation have a name?
2°) Is there a theory of existence and uniqueness of solutions for initial conditions of the form $m(.,0)=\sum_1^N m_i\delta_{a_i}$ ? (One has to properly interpret the product $um$, as $u$ is singular. This amounts to replacing the original $u$ with $u(x)=c\int_{\mathbb R^n\setminus \{x\}} \frac{(y-x)\ m(dy)}{|y-x|^n}$).

Miscellaneous comments: 1.This is one of a family of models of *chemotaxis* in physics and biology, maybe the simplest. 2. For $n=1$ it is related to Burgers equation through a (rather obvious) change of variables. 3. There seems to exist interesting statistical solutions of this equation (not published yet if I'm not mistaken), some of which I believe should provide a paradigmatic example of *spontaneous stochasticity* (ill-posed Cauchy problem with a random solution), an important phenomenon in the physics of turbulence.

Comment: For the parabolic-elliptic Keller-Segel eq there are results concerning measure valued solutions https://www.ceremade.dauphine.fr/~dolbeaul/Preprints/Fichiers/DolbSchm.pdf

Comment: @guacho The diffusion term changes it all. The question is about purely atomic measures with aggregation. Thanks anyway for the reference...

Answer (score 1):

This equation is called aggregation equation (with attractive Newtonian kernel), and if the initial data u(x,0) is compactly supported and in L^infty, local-wellposedness of solution can be found here:
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.299.6417

However I am not aware of any well-posedness theory on measure-valued solutions. (If the initial data is a finite sum of delta functions as you said, one can write the equation as a system of ODEs that describe the trajectory of particles; however such approach will not work for general initial data that is a measure.)

It is indeed related to the Keller-Segel equation which models chemotaxis, except that the Keller-Segel equation has an extra diffusion term.